# What will be the output of the following program?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   printf(" %d\n",'-'-'-'+'/'/'/');
}
```

its giving output as `1`.

I have also tried different combinations but cant make out
the output ?

Comment: what do you expect as output ?

Comment: I just didn't get it how did that output come.

Comment: @Nikhil, if you get your answer, you should accept it.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay that's only possible 15 minutes after posting the question, however.

Comment: missing return type on main

Comment: @Brandin int is assumed by spec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character constant `'-'` has ASCII value 45, while `'/'` has ASCII value 47.  So assuming you're running on a system that uses ASCII or UTF-8 character encodings, the expression evaluates to

```
'-' - '-' + '/' / '/'  == 45 - 45 + 47 / 47 == 0 + 1 == 1
```

Hence the output "1".

**EDIT**

KerrekSB rightly points out that the underlying character set doesn't have to be ASCII; I was simply using it to point out that character constants have a corresponding numeric value.  Regardless of the encoding (ASCII, EBCDIC, UTF-8, etc.), `'-' - '-'` will always evaluate to 0 and `'/' / '/'` will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: How did you conclude that the OP's execution character set was ASCII?

Comment: @KerrekSB hmm... isn't that in the spec?

Comment: @JanDvorak: You tell me - *you're* the one asserting it :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's an assumption, and used mainly for illustrative purposes; regardless of the encoding, `'-' - '-'` will always yield 0, `'/' / '/'` will always yield 1.

Comment: @JohnBode: Then why weigh your post down with all those irrelevant embellishments? It would seem that the concise thought is of greater value here.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's my process.

Comment: UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII-7BIT. Do you have a better example?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Nope. Never used anything outside of ASCII.  I'm aware that other encodings exist (and that UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII), but don't have any relevant examples.

Answer (score 3):

`'-'-'-'+'/'/'/'`

`'-'-'-'` = `ascii(-)` - `ascii(-)` = 0

`'/'/'/'` = `ascii(/)` / `ascii(/)` = 1

Hence 1.

Answer (score 2):

the characters `-` `/` are replaced with there ASCII code and manipulated as they are integers. So `'-' - '-' == 0` and `'/' / '/' == 1` so the output would be `1`

```
'-'-'-'+'/'/'/' == 45 - 45 + 47 / 47
```

So your expression is equivalent to :

```
printf(" %d\n",45 - 45 + 47 / 47); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

gcc -S printf1.c; cat printf1.s

```
    .file   "printf1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string " %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $1, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.8.2-10) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I conclude that '-'-'-'+'/'/'/' is statically evaluated to '1' by compiler ( movl $1, %esi ).

what can be confirmed by

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int i=0;
  for (i=0; i< 10; i ++)
    {
      printf(" %d\n",'-'-'-'+'/'/'/' + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe, however, the interesting part is _why_ it's `1`, not that it's evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: Yes it is interesting and  then original question might deserve more than that -1...

Comment: I was talking about relative interest of the answers, not of the question itself. I'd say the question is poorly researched and not particularly useful (it's at -2 already, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Characters literals are just integral values, so you have a simple, arithmetic expression of integers:

```
'-' - '-' + '/' / '/'
```

By the usual rules of expression evaluation in C, and considering that a number divided by itself is one, this is equal to  `'-' - '-' + 1`, which is `0 + 1`, which is just `1`.